# Lack of communication from HR after internship offer?

Tags: job-offer, human-resources, internship

I'm in college and I am searching for software engineering internships for the summer. I received a phone call and written offer from a big, local company about three weeks ago. The position starts in May.

I accepted the offer in two days (well within their 2 week deadline), and I received a confirmation email for my acceptance. I emailed them and left a voicemail saying that I accepted, was excited to join, and I had a few general questions about the process after accepting (timeline, staff account, etc), especially since the start date for the internship was so far away. I didn't get any response, and I sent a follow up email this past Monday. Still no response.

Is it normal for HR to not respond after an acceptance, and should I also stop sending emails? How much communication should I expect between now and May? Also, is there a possibility they are going back on the offer by just ignoring me? I don't want it to get to May, just for them to say something's wrong because they weren't responding.

Edited to clarify: I think my question is unique because there is such a large gap between now and the start date, and I know my current status (because the offer has already been extended to me). I am just uncertain of the expected behavior of HR for start dates that are far away.

Comment: Yes, it included all of the questions. I sent it 3 weeks ago, right after I accepted the offer. I sent the follow-up email this past Monday (2 days ago).

Comment: Have you received a contract of any kind? Is this a paid internship? What did the confirmation email say - did it mention that you could contact them with any questions?

Comment: Yes, I received a full contract with the start date in May and the pay rate. The confirmation email said that a copy of my signed letter was sent to both me and the recruiter. In the contract, it specifically mentioned an email and phone number to contact with questions. I used that email and phone number. It was also the email that the confirmation email used

Comment: Well, this is well past the interview status, and I've received an offer. Plus, the start date is much farther out (since it's an internship), which is why I feel like it's a different situation.

Comment: If you received a contract and it's all signed, I wouldn't worry. You mentioned it's a big company, they're probably ticked you off as completed and will answer your questions closer to the start date

Comment: Rather than going back on the deal, it's much more likely that they just don't see you as a priority.  if you start in May, there's nothing needs doing until April.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a good chance HR doesn't have those answers**

In the entities with HR departments where I have worked, HR would not have those answers. Timelines (presumably of the internship) would be the purview of your manager. Staff accounts would be part of IT.

I bet that they got the email, planned to ask others about the info and then reply, and then forgot to handle the email. Try getting in touch with your manager.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to let it go, your contract is signed so no need to worry !

Someone in the HR department will take some time, when you arrive in the company, to introduce you to all you need to know.